# How to use fork() to call subroutines in parallel using C

Tags: c, sockets, fork

I have the following code in which I'm running a server using a TCP port. I need to fork and place calls to a subroutine to invoke clients so that they can run in parallel and connect with the server.

As of now, I have just been able to make serial implementation in which calls are placed through a loop, I've just seem to have hit a road block, it will be great if someone can take the pain to go through the code and guide me.

The following is the main. The client subroutine just resides in client.c and seems to work fine. If need be I can paste that too.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in manager, client;
  struct hostent *cp;
  int sockdescriptor, td;
  int len;
  char buf[BLEN];
  int j; 
  int n; 
  int num_nodes;
  pid_t pid;


  key_t key;
  int shmid;
  int *port_num;

  sockdescriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  memset((char *) &manager, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  manager.sin_family = AF_INET;
  manager.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  manager.sin_port = htons((u_short) 0); /* dynamically assigning port */

  bind(sockdescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &manager, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    listen(sockdescriptor, QUELEN);

/***************************** Getting port by getsockname() **********************************/
/*                                                                                            */
/*                                                                                            */
  if(getsockname(sockdescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &manager, &len) == -1){
    perror("getsockname failed!");
    return -1;
  }
/*                                                                                            */    
/*                                                                                            */
/**********************************************************************************************/  
    printf("manager port %d\n", (int) ntohs(manager.sin_port));


/********************************* Creating Shared Memory *************************************/
/*                                                                                            */    
/*                                                                                            */

    key = 1234;

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0){
        perror("shmget is broken!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((port_num = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (int *) -1){
        perror("shmat is broken!");
        exit(1);
    }

    *port_num = (int) ntohs(manager.sin_port);
/*                                                                                            */    
/*                                                                                            */
/**********************************************************************************************/  


   for(j = 0; j < num_nodes ; j++){
    if((pid = fork()) == 0){            // child process

          while(1) {

            len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            td = accept(sockdescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &len);

//                    close(sockdescriptor);            //closing listening socket

                cp = gethostbyaddr((char *) &client.sin_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr), AF_INET);
//              printf("Connected from %s\n", cp->h_name);

                client_num++;   
                    printf("client %d port %d\n",client_num, *port_num);

                sprintf(buf, "%d",nonce);
                send(td, buf, strlen(buf), 0);

                n = recv(td, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

                printf("client %d says %s\n",client_num, buf);

                close(td); /* client request processed, close this client's socket */
                close(sockdescriptor);
                exit(0);
          } // end of while loop
    }
//  else if((pid = fork()) > 0){

    client_prog();  // Calls to this subroutine need to be via forked processes

//  close(td);
//  exit(0);

//  } // else if ends here

} // end of the for loop
```

Comment: Instead of creating a process per client user, you can use `pthreads` to create a thread per user, that will be more resource efficient

Comment: yeah that would be the optimal way to go, but I'm kind of required to make processes here!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're facing? "hitting a road block" is a little ambiguous

Comment: Basically the situation here is the I have a server running in my `main()` code which is scheduled to send and receive some information when a clients connects to it. The problem here is that I want to spawn processes from within the main function so that they can connect to the server. At the moment I have just been able to do this in a serial fashion, by placing calls to the subroutine that invokes the client. I need to place the calls to the client subroutines in parallel.

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be done with sockets? It seems that pipes would be more adequate, since you're controlling both ends of the connection and processes are spawned by the same application.

Answer (score 1):

To have `num_nodes` clients, do:

```
for(j = 0; j<num_nodes; j++)
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(sockdescriptor);
        client_prog();
        exit(0);
    }
```

Then to have a separate process handling each client connection, such that multiple clients can proceed in parallel, I suggest that you replace the entire `for` loop with something like this:

```
while(1) {
    td = accept(sockdescriptor, ...);
    client_num++;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(sockdescriptor);

        /* handle client interaction here */
        send(...) / receive(...)

        exit(0);
    } else {
        close(td);
    }
}
```

Note that there is a race condition: If `num_nodes` is greater than SOMAXCONN, it is possible that connections are dropped. Spawning the server process first does not eliminate the race condition. This sort of thing is safer with pipes, that are pre-opened before fork.

Comment: Hmm..thats a good suggestion, so your thought seems to be that I should take the `fork()` inside the while loop, that will make things cleaner. However, how do I spawn multiple processes to call the `client_prog` routine this way?

Comment: This code will create multiple processes: one for each client connection. It is really hard to help without further details on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let me try and make a better attempt at explaining. So basically I have server running in my `main()`. Now I need to spawn `N` number of processes which place a call to invoke a client. Say the value of `N` is 2. So now 2 processes should be spawned which then place calls to the client subroutine to invoke them, clients then connect with the server and do some message passing.

Comment: @urch: Normally, the server code doesn't create clients; the clients are on a different machine, even.  Unless you are using a different (non-standard) terminology — don't ask about X11. A server process normally hangs around waiting to accept connections, as [jop](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1612355/jop) says.  When the connection arrives, it is handled by a separate 'thread of control' from the thread that goes back to listening for the next connection. The separate thread of control may be a separate process forked from the current one (that seems to be what you need) or a POSIX pthread.

Comment: @urch: Just saw your extra comment...Am I right in thinking you want a client that makes multiple connections to a separate server?  You can do that easily enough with a shell script running clients; you can, if you must, create a process that forks and connects to the server.  It is less clear that you can usefully create a process that connects and forks — they'll all share a single socket and the server won't easily be able to distinguish them. Your `while (1) { ...; exit(0); }` loop really isn't an infinite loop, or even a loop at all.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Agreed. I have been able to get the concurrent server running which handles a client connection via a separate child process and then goes back to listening for more connections on the port. My discussion with you guys is making me think now that what I'm trying to do in `main()` is probably not possible. i.e. run a server and then spawn processes to connect with it.

Comment: I could do this externally via shell script as you mention, is there a way by which I can break up my code into different functions and then achieve the above. Namely. A server and parallel clients connecting to it where the number of spawned clients is equal to N

Comment: You could have a single process responsible for forking both the server and the clients (heck; you could argue that you'd use the shell to do that if you ran it from the command line).  More narrowly, you could have a single executable containing both the server code and the client code, and you just have to make sure that each process forked knows what its task is.  Remember that the each client should close its copy of the server's listening socket if the clients are forked after that has been created, etc.  Yes, you can — should — use functions to encapsulate all this.

Comment: You might have `int main(void) { server(); client(); client(); waitloop(); return 0; }` where the `server()` function is responsible for forking and the child runs the server process, and the `client()` function is responsible for forking and the child runs a client process, and `waitloop()` is a loop around `waitpid()` waiting for all the child processes to die.  Or you can use a loop to run the `client()` function multiple times.  The options are legion. Use good programming techniques throughout, and check for errors, every time.

Comment: hmm..this is an interesting suggestion, let me look into this. To synthesize, your suggestions is that forking to be moved to individual  functions and let the child process of each handle the job. This allows the control to return to main after each function call and code executes without blocking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Even if spawned later, there is a chance that client processes start first and connect to the server socket that has not been created. Even if you open/bind/listen the socket before forking, the problem is still there if number of clients is greater than SOMAXCONN.